# How to change the UItabbar icon image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on an app and want to customize the UItabbar icon image.

I have an image with name about.png this image i want to set as left icon image of my app's UItabbar.
how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

k you use this code and used your own images not the built in one's used your images...

```
- (id)init {
UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newspaper.png"];
UITabBarItem* theItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"News" image:anImage tag:0];
self.tabBarItem = theItem;
[theItem release];
return self;  }
```

newspaper.png is my own image in the tab bar...

k fine now this will be sufficient for your problem...

Comment: can i use this code in delegate implementation file.
it generates an error about tabBarItem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the image for [UITabbarItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can make use of its instance method

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString  *)title image:(UIImage  *)image tag:(NSInteger)tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement init() in viewController in which you are using tab.

```
- (id)init {

if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"Search" bundle:nil]) {
    UIImage* tabImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"];
    UITabBarItem* theItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Search" image:tabImage tag:0];
    self.tabBarItem = theItem;
    [theItem release];
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are always two ways of doing this by programmatically or by using visually(using IB)

Programmatically:-

```
UITabBarItem* theItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"News" image:anImage tag:0];
```

use this or if you are doing visually:-
Click on the particular tab icon in the IB and chose customize and icon and give the name of particular icon file.

May this will solve your problem...

Comment: i'm not saying you used built in images of Xcode just look at my new answer posted in ur list...

Answer (score 0):

You can change it like.
in tabbar controller delegate method

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

{
    if([tabBarController selectedIndex] == 0)
    {
        [viewController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect.png"]];
    }    
}
```

through this you can change your tabbaritem image.

Or you can use directly in your view controllers init(or ViewWillAppear) method, like

```
        [viewController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

First you make class this code :

```
extension UITabBarController {

    func addIcon(icon : UIImage, deselectIcon : UIImage, buttonIndex : Int, currentPage : Int){

        var index = 0
        for view in view.subviews {

            if view.subviews.count > 3 {

                for _view in view.subviews {

                    if index == buttonIndex {

                        for v in _view.subviews {

                            if v is UIImageView {
                                v.removeFromSuperview()
                            }
                        }

                        let img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: _view.frame.width / 2 - 15, y: 4, width: 30, height: 30))

                        if buttonIndex == currentPage {
                            img.image = icon
                        }else{
                            img.image = deselectIcon
                        }
                        img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

                        _view.addSubview(img)


                    }
                    index += 1
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

In `didload` you call function :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1 ) {
        self.tabBarController?.addIcon(icon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Shop"), deselectIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Shop"), buttonIndex: 1, currentPage: 1)
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    tabBarController?.addIcon(icon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Shop"), deselectIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Shop"), buttonIndex: 1, currentPage: 1)

}
```